# React access type prop via passed variable

Tags: reactjs

I have a type with many properties, and I was wondering if it's possible to use one function to update any of the properties. So for example I have

```
export type RequestData = {
  Status: string,
  RequestDate: Moment,
  RequesterName: string,
  RequesterId: number,
  BudgetCategory: string,
  BudgetSubcategory: string,
  BudgetTeamCode: string
}
```

I can update BudgetSubcategory with this

```
interface ConnectedState {
  requestData: Store.RequestData
}

interface ConnectedDispatch {
  updateRequestData: (requestData: Store.RequestData) => void
}

function mapStateToProps(state: Store.All): ConnectedState {
  return {
    requestData: getRequestData(state),
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<Store.All>): ConnectedDispatch {
return {
  updateRequestData: (requestData: Store.RequestData) => dispatch(updateRequestData(requestData))
 };
}

class MainContainer extends React.Component<OwnProps & ConnectedState & ConnectedDispatch, {}> {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  updateBudgetSubcategory = (subcategory: string) => {
    this.props.updateRequestData({...this.props.requestData, BudgetSubcategory: subcategory });
   }
}
```

I want to be able to update any of these props one at a time, without having to create a separate function for each of them. Is it possible to pass a property name along with the value to do something like

```
updateRequestDataProperty = (propertyToUpdate: string, value: string) => {
  this.props.updateRequestData({...this.props.requestData, propertyToUpdate: value });
}
```

Comment: Yed its possible. Did you try it? You can also just send the whole updated object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
updateRequestDataProperty = (propertyToUpdate, value) => {
  this.props.updateRequestData({
    ...this.props.requestData,
    [propertyToUpdate]: value  // field name: value of `propertyToUpdate`
  });
};
```

Comment: you're welcome! if this or any other answer has helped you, please [upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others find it in the future.